# Biztalk Server 2010 white space inconsistent behaviour

Tags: xml, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am creating a .csv file, using Biztalk Server 2010.

The input message is in XML format and using Flat-File Assembler in custom pipeline.

I have a field in which I am sending 10 white spaces.

Here is my Code :

```
<Records xmlns="">
    <Sequence>0015808137001</Sequence>
    <Date>          </Date>
    <FileDate>04/03/2014</FileDate>
</Records>
```

The elements in in both input and output schema is string type.
The issue is when the file get created, it sometimes consists of 10 white spaces and sometimes not.

I have tried this using XML Transmit pipeline, but the issue occurs in the output XML too.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: What other content appears?  Meaning when it's not 10 spaces.

Comment: The default value for that element I have set; which is ""

Comment: So you mean it's either 10 spaces or 0 characters?

Comment: I have set inverted commas in default. So it shows "" not 0 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inserting whitespace upstream, like in the Map, you can use some properties on the element in the FlatFile Schema:

- Minimum Length with Pad Character
- Pad Character Type
- Pad Character

That way, you will always get 10 characters, padded, if that satisfies the requirement.

Comment: My schema is not flat file schema, as the fields are not of fixed length.

Comment: "I am creating a .csv file" would mean a Flat File Schema.  Is there something else involved?

Comment: I haven't used Flat File Schema, instead have used Flat File disassembler in pipeline.

Comment: So, the Flat File Disassembler requires a Flat File annotated Schema...that's just how it works.  In the Flat File Schema is where these options would be.